# Sorting TemplateField when a boundfield is sorted in a Gridview Control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to know how can i sort a templateField when i'm actually sorting a Boundfield in a GridView control. Technology used is ASP.NET.

Here is my code :

```
<asp:GridView  ID="classGrid" BorderStyle="Solid"
    runat="server" AllowSorting="true" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="Azure" AllowPaging="true" OnSorting="onSorting" EnableViewState="true"
    ShowFooter="True" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" OnRowCommand="onRowCommand"
    EmptyDataRowStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"  EmptyDataText="No datas available" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
    SelectedRowStyle-ForeColor="#FF6600" SelectedRowStyle-BackColor="#FF9966" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#9999FF">
    <Columns >
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button Text = "Supprimer" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' CommandName="Del" CausesValidation="false"/>
                <asp:Button Text = "Editer" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' CommandName="Maj"  CausesValidation="false" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField  DataField="name" HeaderStyle-BorderStyle="Outset" HeaderText="Nom de la classe" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" SortExpression="name"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="NbEtu" ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="Nb Etudiant actuel" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="minEtu" HeaderText="Nb Etudiant Min" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="maxEtu" HeaderText="Nb Etudiant Max" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" /> 
    </Columns> 
</asp:GridView>
```

Thanks in advance,

Best regards

Comment: You are sorting a datasource based upon a column you have selected.

Comment: `SortExpression` property can be provided for `TemplateField` - however the actual expression must be a column name/ property name of the data source item.

Comment: Thank you , i found the solution by modifying de commandArgument by : '<%# Bind("ID") %>' :)